# Link-to the previous nested resource in ember

Tags: ember.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', { path: '/stores/'+store_id+'/users' });
    this.route('user', { path: '/stores/'+store_id+'/users/:user_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('devices', { path: '/devices' });
    });
});
```

On devices page I want to go back to `/users/:user_id`.

Here is my `template/devices.hbs`

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>model</th>
       <th>user_id</th>
   </tr>
   {{#each model as |device|}}
   <tr>
     <td>{{device.model}}</td>
     <td>{{#link-to "???" ?? ???}}{{device.user_id}}{{/link-to}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

I don't how to go back to the specific resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `user.index`, because it's fully qualified route name with URL: `/users/:user_id`.

```
{{#link-to 'user.index'}}Go back to /users/:user_id{{/link-to}}

<table>
   <tr>
       <th>model</th>
       <th>user_id</th>
   </tr>
   {{#each model as |device|}}
   <tr>
     <td>{{device.model}}</td>
     <td>{{#link-to "???" ?? ???}}{{device.user_id}}{{/link-to}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: There is no route named Go back to /users/:user_id   :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @daniel-kmak for the tips. The route is fully qualified at `user.index`

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>model</th>
       <th>user_id</th>
   </tr>
   {{#each model as |device|}}
   <tr>
     <td>{{device.model}}</td>
     <td>{{#link-to 'user.index'}}{{device.user_id}}{{/link-to}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```